# Azure Read API for Vector PDFs

Tags: azure, pdf, vector, ocr, vision-api

I am working on the solution for OCR using Azure Read API, and it provides out of box solution for raster PDFs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#read-api

but I don't see if it can support vector based PDFs. I have other solution by using some third party libraries such as Aspose and PDFxStream, but prefer if I can stay within just Azure Vision API ecosystem.

So my question is is it possible to use Read API for vector PDF, and if not what is best practical approach I could use?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question: yes, it supports Vector based PDFs, although it is not explicitly mentioned in API documentation. We checked both through Azure portal and through API code and it works. No problem with mixing raster and vector based PDFs.